# OPE Energy-momentum tensor with itself

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Is it possible to derive the OPE of the energy-momentum tensor with itself without using the definition of the Virasoro algebra but just the OPE with a primary field? So in terms of formulas can it be proven that:

$$T(z)\phi(w,\bar{w})=\frac{h}{(z-w)^{2}} \phi(w,\bar{w})+\frac{1}{z-w}\partial_w\phi(w,\bar{w}) +...$$ $$\Longrightarrow  T(z)T(w)=\frac{\frac{c}{2}}{(z-w)^{4}}+\frac{2T(w)}{(z-w)^{2}}+\frac{\partial_{w}T(w)}{z-w}+... $$

Comment: The stress tensor is not a primary field -- so no, you cannot derive the $TT$ OPE from the $T\phi$ OPE.

Comment: These lecture notes https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9108028 seem to imply it is possible. It seems that one needs to consider $[Q_{\epsilon_2},[Q_{\epsilon_1},\Phi(w,\bar{w})]$ for $\Phi$ a primary field.

Comment: So, I worked a little bit on this and I believe that considering the identity $[[Q_{\epsilon_2},Q_{\epsilon_1}],\Phi(w,\bar{w})]=[Q_{\epsilon_2},[Q_{\epsilon_1},\Phi(w,\bar{w})]]-[Q_{\epsilon_1},[Q_{\epsilon_2},\Phi(w,\bar{w})]]$ of operators allows you to compute the last two terms of the OPE and leaves open the possibility for there to be the first term. The left hand side is computed in terms of the OPE $TT$ while the two terms in the right hand side are computed in terms of the OPE $T\phi$. If I get the chance, I will try to make this an answer.

Comment: Thank you actually VERY much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the transformation rule given in Polchinski's equation (2.4.26):

$$T'(z')=(\partial z')^{-2}T(z)-\frac{c}{12} \{z',z\}$$

You can use the $(\partial z')^{-2}$ piece to prove the residues using the exact same steps as you would with a primary field, and so you could skip those steps if you are already convinced of the OPE for the primary fields and can see that the steps would be identical.

However, we also have the Schwarzian piece $\{z',z\}$ to contend to when calculating the residues.

We calculate the shift using the residue theorem and the same concepts as for the primary fields:

$$\delta _\rho T=\oint -\frac{dz}{2\pi i}\rho (z)T(z)T(0)=\mbox{Res}_{z\rightarrow 0}(-\rho (z)T(z)T(0))$$

Recall that $\rho $ is the infinitesimal and holomorphic shift in the coordinate: $z'=z+\rho $, so to target the fourth-order denominator in the OPE to survive in the residue, we would use $\rho =\varepsilon z^3$. This would make $\partial z'=1+3\varepsilon z^2$.

As usual, $T'(z')\approx T'(z)+\varepsilon z^3\partial T$, and $(\partial z')^{-2}T(z)\approx (1-2\varepsilon z^2)T(z)$ using some Taylor approximations. So: $T'(z)+\varepsilon z^3\partial T\approx T'(z')\approx (1-2\varepsilon z^2)T(z)-\frac{c}{12} \{z',z\}$

Then $\delta _\rho T=T'(z)-T(z)\approx -2\varepsilon z^2T(z)-\varepsilon z^3\partial T-\frac{c}{12}\{z',z\}$. Note that all of the terms that are regular in $z$ will get dropped because we are taking $\lim _{z\rightarrow 0}$ when calculating the residue.

The Schwarzian is defined in Polchinski (2.4.27): $$\{z',z\}\equiv \frac{2 \partial ^3 z' \partial z'-3 \partial ^2z'\partial ^2z}{2\partial z'\partial z'}$$

And when crunched this works out to: $\{z',z\}=\dfrac{6\varepsilon (1-6\varepsilon z^2)}{(1+3\varepsilon z^2)^2}$. Taylor expanding this, we have: $\{z',z\}=6\varepsilon -72 \varepsilon ^2z^2+O(z^4)$. Again, dropping regular terms from the residue this leaves us with the desired central charge term of $-\dfrac{\varepsilon c}{2}$ in the shift of $\delta _\rho T$.

We can move back into the residue to recover the fourth-order denominator term in the OPE because we multiplied by the positive third power of $\rho =\varepsilon z^3$, and also noting the negative sign inside of the integral, this recovers the $\sim +\dfrac{c/2}{z^4}$ piece in the OPE. And, we skipped proving the first and second order pieces in the OPE by using what we already knew about primaries, as was requested by the original poster. This gives us the full OPE:

$$T(z)T(0)\sim \frac{c/2}{z^4}+\frac{2T(0)}{z^2}+\frac{\partial T}{z}$$

We can put the $w$'s back into the OPE by using some radial ordering, but that step is left to the reader.